# How to handle System Popups using webdriver ??

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

How to handle System Popups webdriver ?? Is it possible ?

Case : Have to upload a file by click and select a file in system pop Instead of using Sendkeys()

Answer (score 2):

No, Selenium can't handle windows/objects other then Browser content. i need to use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/) OR [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to handle OS based popups.